# C++ vector debug implementation

Tags: c++, debugging, vector, iterator

While learning c++ I went through the pains of learning what iterators were, and exactly how to use them.  Then, I went through the pain of learning what function calls invalidate iterators, and spotting them quickly.  I've been following questions lately and have noticed that a *very common* theme is people not realizing that **calling `vector::erase()` invalidates iterators.**  This made me wonder if there were a *debug implementation* of `vector` that does *runtime* checking against vector valid-ness?

My initial thoughts were that it would have to be a wrapper around vector that basically tracked all existing iterators, and set an `isValid` boolean when an action was performed that invalidated them.  Then, when dereferencing or incrementing, `isValid` could be checked.

This would help diagnose more obscure errors where the `erase()` call is nested (accidentally, or unknowingly) deep within a function call, while that same vector is being iterator over.

Does anyone know of such an implementation, or any reasons why one should not be used?

EDIT: I am using linux and g++.

Comment: ...ooh, throw lots of redundant tech at something that could be avoided via reading the documentation... ;)

Comment: @Nim: I agree, but mistakes are made, and catching them during the debugging process is desired over saying 'he should've read the docs' when it crashes in production.

Comment: @JaredC, unit tests were invented for this same reason... ;) I thoroughly dislike the idea of running "special code" in testing vs. production...

Comment: You do realize that when you have to use erase() then you probably should not use vector, as erase in a vector is very slow - has linear complexity (except at the end).

Comment: @Tometzky: That's crazy.  There are perfectly valid reasons for using `vector` when `erase()` is needed.

Comment: @Nim: No, unit tests were invented to test small chunks of your code. They don't necessarily help you detect if you use an invalidated iterator, partly because it may often *seem to work*, especially in simple contexts such as a unit test. There's little reason not to enable additional error checking while debugging.

Comment: @JaredC: of course, either for small vectors or very rare erase

Comment: Any operation changing length of vector can invalidate iterators: erase, push_back, insert etc. I'm not sure about pop_back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft's implementation does some debug checking ([ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985982%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), and [ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985965%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)).  It checks specifically for range, so I'm not sure if the erase() scenario fits or not.

Edit for jalf's contribution:

It appears that GCC (and g++) has similar functionality:

[stackoverflow.com/questions/2567997/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567997/) and

[gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug_mode.html](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug_mode.html)

Comment: GCC's standard library supports a similar debug mode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567997/using-a-checked-stl-implementation-anything-available-for-free and http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug_mode.html

Comment: @JaredC: Ahh, sorry.  Not sure about GCC.

Comment: @jalf: Thanks for the links, that's exactly what I needed.  I knew there had to be an implementation of this.

Answer (score 0):

That is found in Microsoft STD library implementation..

When an iterator is invalidated, it means using it to access an element will cause runtime error, exactly like you want....

Comment: Isn't the current behavior undefined, not _always_ a runtime error?

Comment: @JaredC: yep, the behavior mandated by the standard is simply "undefined" (or to be more precise, no behavior is mandated by the standard). No runtime error is required.